# Странное поведение оператора -- в PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
$b=10;
$f=$b + $b + --$b;
echo $f;  //выведет 29, вроде правильно

$b=10;
$f=$b + --$b;
echo $f;  //выведет 18, почему не 19 !?!?!?

//или еще вот так
$b=10;
$f=$b + $b + $b--;
echo $f;  //выведет 30, ожидаемо, но, смотрим дальше

$b=10;
$f=$b + $b--;
echo $f;  //выведет...пауза...затаили дыхание...барабанный бой...19!!!!
```

Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь сможет объяснить, почему так происходит. Версия PHP 7.1.6 (xampp v3.2.2)

Comment: Сначала идет уменьшение переменной $b на 1 и только потом ее сложение с собой ;) Тут http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php посмотрите **Пример #2 Неопределенный порядок вычисления**

Comment: Спасибо! Я то думал WTF?,  но ссылка на мануал все прояснила. Оказывается, так задумано, неопределенный порядок вычисления, понимаешь. Разработчики ребята с юморком

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень [интересный приоритет операторов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php) у этого вашего PHP. К тому же сложение выполняется по порядку, но слагаемые вычисляются наоборот справа налево **в данном случае. Этот порядок не гарантируется, поэтому результат на других версиях PHP может отличаться.** К примеру на версии 5.0.4 порядок тот же, но слагаемые вычисляются более привычно слева направо, см. UPD.

Уравнение первое `$f=$b + $b + --$b;`

1. Складываем $b + $b и запоминаем результат $temp = 20.
2. Справа инкремент, выполняем его и складываем с левым значением $temp.
3. 20 + 9 = 29.

Уравнение второе `$f = $b + --$b;`

1. Справа инкремент, выполняем его и получаем 9.
2. Слева ссылка на $b, раскрываем ее и там у нас лежит после инкремента девятка.
3. 9 + 9 = 18.

Уравнение третье `$f=$b + $b + $b--;`

1. Складываем $b + $b и запоминаем результат $temp = 20.
2. Справа преинкремент, выполняем его возвращая 10 и складываем с левым значением $temp.
3. 20 + 10 = 30

Уравнение четвертое `$f=$b + $b--;`

1. Слева инкремент, выполняем его возвращая 10 и складываем с левым значением.
2. Слева ссылка, раскрываем ее и получаем 9.
3. 9 + 10 = 19.

Но гораздо веселее складывать такое: `$f=$b + $b + $b-- + $b + $b;` и `$f=$b + $b + --$b + $b + $b;`

**P.S.** Лучше избегайте таких конструкций, результат которых может быть неопределенным и никак не гарантируется разработчиками.

**UPD..** На версии 5.0.4 порядок тот же, но слагаемые вычисляются более привычно слева направо. Поэтому в примерах выше сначала раскроются ссылки слева и потом будет вычислен инкремент справа.

Уравнение первое `$f=$b + $b + --$b;`

1. Складываем $b + $b и запоминаем результат $temp = 20.
2. Складываем с левым значением $temp полученный инкремент.
3. 20 + 9 = 29.

Уравнение второе `$f = $b + --$b;`

1. Слева ссылка на $b, раскрываем ее и получаем 10.
2. Справа инкремент, выполняем его и получаем 9.
3. 10 + 9 = 19.

Уравнение третье `$f=$b + $b + $b--;`

1. Складываем $b + $b и запоминаем результат $temp = 20.
2. Складываем с левым значением $temp преинкремент 10.
3. 20 + 10 = 30

Уравнение четвертое `$f=$b + $b--;`

1. Слева ссылка, раскрываем ее и получаем 10.
2. Слева инкремент, выполняем его возвращая 10 и складываем с левым значением.
3. 10 + 10 = 20.

Comment: А теперь тоже самое но для версии 5.0 напишите? :)

Comment: @Visman, увы, онлайн тестера для 5.0 не нашел в инете, что бы я мог посмотреть для него результаты) Но на всякий случай выделил жирным предложение с вопросом о том, так задумано спецификацией или так просто получилось при реализации.

Comment: О неопределенном порядке вычисления прямо сказано в документации по ссылке http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php И результаты в php 4.xx/5.0.xx были у этих примеров совершенно другие.

Comment: @Visman, спасибо, не осведомлен по этому поводу, внес соответствующие корректировки в ответ.

Comment: `онлайн тестера для 5.0 не нашел в инете` - как же так http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/  ........